# N-channel MOSFET used to control 5V relay from 3.3V ESP8266 pin

Tags: mosfet, relay, 5v, 3.3v

Today I "played" with a relay for the first time.

I only had an N-channel MOSFET available (an IRLZ44N) and wanted to control the relay from an ESP8266's GPIO pin - i.e. use a 3.3V signal to control the relay's input pin, which expects 0 or 5V.

[image: ESP8266 controlling a 5V relay with an N-channel MOSFET]

- I had a 10K resistor handy, so I used it to current-limit the fet's Gate. To my understanding, MOSFETs only care about voltage, not current - so a "big" current limiter at the gate shouldn't matter anyway.
- When the IRLZ44N is off, the relay's input is connected to the 5V over R1 - and when it's on, the input goes to ground. At that operational mode a resistor is needed; without it, the 5V would end up going directly to ground.

The circuit works - I tested it and the relay responds as expected. But measuring voltages, I saw that the voltage after R1 is not 5V; it's less, since some current goes in the relay's input. In doing so, the voltage drops from 5V to 3.5V; there's approximately 5mA going in the relay's input, and 1.5V ends up being wasted on R1.

It seems that if I had used a larger R1, the circuit wouldn't work - the voltage would drop too far. And as-is, 3.5V may be a marginal situation for the relay. **EDIT: Using the 3.3V signal from the ESP directly on the IN1 input doesn't trigger the relay - so it seems the 3.5V we reach with this circuit is indeed borderline**

Another disappointing thing about this circuit: when the relay is off, we  waste current through R1.

Can you guys recommend a better circuit to use with my IRLZ44N, to turn the ESP8266's 3.3V to 5V and optimally control my relay?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm, mechanical relays have coils, not "In, Gnd, Vcc". Do you have an actual relay or is it a module? And while ideal FETs gates don't care about current, real FETs do have a parasitic capacitor, so a lower resistor would be better (not that much of a problem here though).

Comment: It's this relay: https://tkkrlab.nl/wiki/Arduino_KY-019_5V_relay_module - indeed, it's a module.

Comment: It is likely your N-FET circuit is unnecessary and somewhat unhelpful, however your link does not provide any credible documentation of the relay's *internal* circuit, so it's not possible to make any definitive statements.   The PCB seems simple enough that you might be able to reverse engineer it by the combination of visual inspection and some ohm meter measurements when unconnected to anything.

Comment: @ChrisStratton My first attempt was obviously using the 3.3V signal as-is into the IN1 pin of the module - but the relay didn't fire, so the "unnecessary" part is at least debatable :-) Regardless, assuming that we indeed need 5V and that the only accessible FET is this N-channel one... any idea on a better circuit to raise the 3.3 to 5?

Comment: Found a "schematic" for the module on [this](http://www.adrirobot.it/sensori/37_in_1/KY-019-5V-relay-module/37_in_1-KY-019_5V_relay_module.htm#Circuito_elettrico_e_PCB_del_modulo_KF-301) website. Its likely incorrect as S8550 is a PNP part, they probably meant S8050.

Comment: I don't know what exactly your K1 block is, but it's not a "relay".  Relays are just coils on the input side.  Since you have VCC, IN, and GND connections for the input, there is apparently some active circuitry in front of a real relay.  Without a datasheet, there is no way to know what that block really wants.  All that said, driving a real relay would be simpler and can be done with a subset of the parts you are already using.

Comment: @ttsiodras - you can probably use 3.3v on the input, but may need to supply close to 5v on the Vcc line.  However the safety of this combination (for the ESP8266) can't truly be determined without knowing the internal circuit of the relay module.  It would be safe in the *most likely* circuit, but that is only a guess, we don't actually know what is inside, so we don't actually know if it is safe.

Comment: @ChrisStratton "you may need to supply close to 5V on the VCC" - I am already doing that; unsure what you mean here. This module was apparently designed for Arduinos - you feed it 5V on VCC, and depending on the IN1 signal, it connects/disconnects the NO/NC side of the relay.

Comment: If it's designed in the *sensible* way, 5v on the supply and 3.3v on the input would work.  But we don't actually know what is in there.  Try to measure how much of the supply voltage is dropped across the relay coil itself vs. across the suspected transistor, when it is trying to be "on".

Comment: @ChrisStratton I would rather avoid messing with/disassembling the module. The reason I posted the question was to see if someone could provide a better circuit on the left - but sadly everyone focuses on the relay.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster is **unable to provide the required engineering documentation** and **directly refuses to take measurements** of the undocumented device which could reveal the necessary information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following schematic on [this](http://www.adrirobot.it/sensori/37_in_1/KY-019-5V-relay-module/37_in_1-KY-019_5V_relay_module.htm#Schema_di_collegamento_del_modulo_con_Arduino) website. **Its likely incorrect** in some parts though, as S8550 is a PNP part, they probably meant [S8050](https://www.zahranvane.com/download/S8050.pdf.3d9e9d17e0eb11df38de344989ecc805).

[image]

Since you stated that directly plugging a 3.3V signal didn't work, you can try one of the following (considering your N-FET limitation):

- Use your IRLZ44 to directly drive the relay
- Put a resistor in parallel with R3, to increase the current going into the NPNs base and try to trigger it with 3.3V again.

p.s.: I hope you aren't actually connecting GND to AC with your relay as it could be quite unpleasant/dangerous:

[image]

Comment: About the p.s: :-)  About the rest, if that was the schematic of my relay module, I don't see why the 3.3V of the ESP wouldn't work as-is; the BJT would conduct, no? But TBH, I am still hoping for a solution that doesn't involve opening the relay module - i.e. a circuit that gives a "better" 5V than my puny 3.5V (using the N-FET).

Comment: Well, you could use a smaller R3, but it will draw more power when you want the relay to be off. I also thought it was strange that 3.3V wasn't enough to switch the transistor on.. but maaybe the base resistor is higher than 1k or, the transistor has low Hfe. Might be worth the try just adding a resistor in parallel.

Comment: The 3.3v signal input is probably fine, but the relay may need to be supplied something closer to 5v.  However, either your original measurement of 5 mA is wrong, or this is not the circuit and component values of your relay module.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I assumed OP was always providing 5V power regardless of the input signal.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am supplying 5V at VCC - depending on IN1 (0/5V) the module connects/disconnects the NO/NC side of the relay. For some reason everyone is focusing on the relay, though - my question stands regardless of relays... From 3.3 to 5V, via an n-FET...

Comment: @ttsiodras - people are ignoring the 3.3v to 5v via an NFET as an N channel device is the wrong part for sourcing current from a higher voltage, and because level translation is tangential to an efficient solution to your problem.

Comment: @ChrisStratton "the wrong part for the job" - I take this as an answer that there is no good solution to this problem with N-FETs. Can you post it as such? I respect your experience, and have followed you advice in the past - I just wanted to make sure I am not missing anything obvious.

Comment: It's not that there are no good solutions, but (and I'm sorry if this sounds harsh), most sensible people would avoid providing information about how to drive a module that you yourself can't find/provide schematics of. So, no datasheet, no solution.

Comment: @WesleyLee Thanks, Wes. I was hoping for a generic solution to the 3.3->5 with n-fets, but understand from the reactions here that there is none.

Comment: There are other level shifters with N-FETs other than the one you used such as [this](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/f/3/3/4/4/526842ae757b7f1b128b456f.png) one, but they will have the same problem as R3 since they also depend on pull-ups. Other options would be more complicated than just directly driving the relay with your IRLZ44. (Maybe a high side N-FET? Then you would need some sort of drive voltage way higher than 3.3V for the gate..)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3V relays and relay modules are available.

I have had similar a problem and tested a BT136 on 10W LED bulb and it worked.

BT136 only only needs 10mA at 2V but is a health-hazard if no optocoupler are used.

\ref [ESP MCU, directly drive BT136](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/620520/esp-mcu-directly-drive-bt136)