# ESP MCU, directly drive BT136

Tags: relay, esp8266, triac

I have questions about driving a *BT136* TRIAC using a port of ESP8266-NodeMCU-12E.
I have tested BT136: if you apply 1.2V from a AA cell between Gate and T2, this result in T1 and T2 conducting for 220VAC.
My questions are:
(1) Can I use my NodeMCU's D2 pin (which is +3V) to drive BT136 directly without using any optocoupler?
(2) Does this harm my MCU?

Comment: Yes, you can, but when the BT136 fails short for some reason or you have HV bursts on the grid, the ESP may get damaged. A small isolating transformer (e.g. 4 mH 1:1) should work here if you know the phase angle and can place a 100us pulse in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering

> (1) Can I use my NodeMCU's D2 pin (which is +3V) to drive BT136 directly without using any optocoupler?

*Yes you can, but it doesn’t mean you should*.
The circuit can be made to work, especially if:
(a) TRIAC_T1 and ESP_ground are connected to the Neutral side of 220VAC,
(b) TRIAC operates on smaller loads,
(c) TRIAC uses a Snubber,
(d) the Gate-ESP connection uses a current limiting resistor.

> (2) Does this harm my MCU?

If you believe that everything will always be right, then **it could be designed to not harm** the MCU - but there is **no assurance** and it is a *gamble*:
Reality can play tricks - remember [Murphy’s law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law) - and *in practice you would be increasing the chance of damaging the MCU or even exposing humans to higher risk*.

Many things can go wrong and backfire, from a power-on overload or overheat or voltage spike, damaging the TRIAC.
There is **no assurance that a damaged TRIAC cannot expose its Gate to higher AC levels**.  The  MCU could then be  “deep-fried” in overvoltages and AC, being destroyed.  Or someone simply reverses Phase/Live and Neutral, the MCU would then be “live-connected”.
If the MCU is connected to something else, including a switch or button, the person would be exposed to potential electrical shocks: very unwise, to say the least.

The easiest solution to **assure *Galvanic insulation*** (to designed levels) is to **drive the TRIAC with an Opto-coupler**.
Or alternatively to drive the TRIAC with pulse transformers (nowadays seldom used).  Or simply to drive the load using a relay.

Comment: I test, I worked my ESP is safe, so far I am also alive. I check using tester which is in dictating that it has live voltage. Which is today if I would touch I might be killed from 240VAC

Comment: I m unable get 3V relay and I don't want 2voltage for my project. Just 3.3V for all.

Comment: @kdm6389, You said above that you measured the ESP and it shows a “live” voltage level. This may be with a high impedance (capacitive coupling - not that bad) or low impedance (low resistance) at higher voltage levels. This later one can be dangerous. Remember that a chain is as strong as the resistance of the weakest link. Redundancy in safety features act as multiple chains: if one breaks, the other chain avoids dropping de load. I tried to answer the questions you made. We can discuss other concerns too, but please be clear about what you need and if I know, I will try to help.

Comment: @kdm6389, about the **relay**: it was a comment to show the concept of galvanic insulation, assuring safety. There are cheap and easy ways you can step-up (boost) from 3.3V to 5V and drive a relay, _using the same single 3.3V power supply_. If you are interested, ask me on that. **Optocoupler**: an opto-triac was my first / preferred suggestion = it provides galvanic insulation, protecting the MCU, the LED side operates on 3.3V from the MCU, while the the Triac side drives your bigger Triac. IF you just need to connect sides (you don’t need)  always use the GND (of 3V3) = Neutral (from 220V).

Answer (score 1):

> can I use my NodeMCU's D2 pin (which is +3V) to drive BT136 directly without using any optocoupler?

Yes. The DC GND (ESP's supply GND) should be connected to L (phase) or N (neutral), depending on how you connect the triac.

The biggest problem here is not the risk of harming the ESP/MCU, but the risk of being electrocuted. If you touch the ESP8266 you may get shocked.

Another risk is to connect the ESP to your PC over a USB port while the triac is connected to the grid. Remember that your PC's USB port connects directly to the PE (protective earth). Therefore PE becomes the ESP's DC ground. Since the ESP's DC ground should also be connected to the grid to drive the triac there's a risk of shorting the L to PE. The fault current will flow through the ESP.

So the safest method is to use either an optocoupler or an isolated supply (e.g. battery).